# Why does `source ~/.aliases` not work in .zshrc?

Tags: zsh, alias

```
user@localhost ~ % zsh --version
zsh 5.5.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
me@localhost ~ % lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
Release:    28
Codename:   TwentyEight
```

`~/.zshrc:`

```
... Details omitted ...
source ~/.aliases
cat ~/.aliases
... Details omitted ...
```

command prompt:

```
user@localhost ~ % zsh
alias ls='exa'
alias grep='rg'
user@localhost ~ %
```

So `~/.zshrc` is executed, but the aliases didn't have any effect.

It works if I run `source ~/.aliases` in the shell.

I've been trying for hours now without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: you were right! my zshrc contained aliases for grep and ls. thank you! if you want you can add an answer which I will accept, so you get your deserved rep ;)

Comment: In this case _Details_ matter `;)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably something that is sourced later changes these aliases.

Add `alias sanitycheck='echo sane'` to your `~/.aliases` and run `sanitycheck` in the `~/.zshrc` just after you source `~/.aliases`. Log in anew. If you get `sane` then you will know `source ~/.aliases` worked.

Investigate what happens later in your `~/.zshrc`. Hopefully you will discover other aliases for `ls` and `grep`.